# Populating django model with objects from other model

Tags: django, model

I'm new to django, but working on an app for a volunteer sailing organization in my local area. Not sure how to ask this question since it's fairly general but I want the following to happen based on two models;

Yacht class (boat name, skipper, color, etc.)

Race_Event class (event date, time results for each boat)

Step 1: The user will need to create a Race_Event each week. I want the boats from the Yacht model to be loaded into the Race_Event.
Step 2: The user will enter race times for each boat.

Is there a way to pre-load objects from one model into another? With a ForeignKey the user has to add the boats each time. Any direction for me to research would be helpful.

Here is the simplified code so far;

```
class Yacht (models.Model):

    yacht_classes = [('A', 'A'),('A1', 'A1'),]
    yacht_type = [('J-29','J-29'),('J-24','J-24'),]

    yacht_name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    yacht_type = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=yacht_type, 
    default='J-29')
    yacht_class = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=yacht_classes)
    skipper = models.ForeignKey(Skipper, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.yacht_name


class Event (models.Model):
    race_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    #yachts = #how to Include Yacht.objects.all() to the field?

class Results (models.Model):
    pass
```

Thanks

Comment: Do all the Yacht instances need to be associated with the new RaceEvent instance?

Comment: Yes. The idea would be to leave the time as null if a yacht didn't race, and internal logic would handle the result tabulation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, u can use signals...
after objects is saved u can call post_save and add all yachts to race
more => https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#post-save

but i dont think this is good way...

(not every time all the data must be present or must be saved => this save rows in database)

i recomment you to use m2M between race and ship with throught table where  time is  saved in table between.

then its on you how you present this problem to end-user.

with this solution you save only data which are needed.

this can be done with

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Thanks I will read up on both links. Assuming that all the boats are always to populate a race event (they want to show the boats that did not race as well), how would you populate a race even with a post_save signal?

Comment: well, post_save signal is always called when race is saved.

i dont know how your model looks like so i cant tell how to do it.. propably if m2m is used it will be done with multiple add of every ship to race.

Comment: Apologies. I have added the code to the original post.

Comment: How would you add all yachts to the Event in the model above?